# A question on linearly independent vectors in a Banach space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Given a list of linearly independent vectors $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ in a Banach space. If for each $1 \leq i\leq n$, there is a sequence of vectors $\{y_m^{(i)}\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $x_i$. Then when $m$ is big enough, whether $\{y_m^{(i)}:1 \leq i\leq n\}$ is also linearly independent?

Thank you for all helps!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Suppose for the sake of convenience that the $y$'s are dependent for every $m$. Choose $c_m^i$ with $$\sum_{i=1}^nc_m^iy_m^i=0,$$**and**, say, $$\sum_{i=1}^n|c_m^i|=1.$$Now the vectors $c_m\in\Bbb R^n$ have a *non-zero* accumulation point...

Comment: very nice proof!

Answer (score 1):

If this Banach space has finite dimension, you can form the matrix $X$ using expansion of $x_i$'s as columns. Since $\lbrace x_i \rbrace$ is a linearly independent system of vectors, ${\rm det}\, X \neq 0$. And you can also form the matrix $Y_m$ using expansions of $y_m^{(i)}$ in the same basis. Then ${\rm det} \; Y_m$ is also non-zero from some moment — this is just a consequence of continuity of ${\rm det}$.

Comment: Quite interesting downvote :)

Answer (score -1):

This is not true, even in the simplest case of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Take $x_1, x_2$ as the standard basis, $y^{(1)}_m=(1,1/m)$, $y^{(2)}_m=(1/m,1)$.

Comment: But $(1,1/m)$ and $(1/m,1)$ are linearly independent when $m>1$, right?

Comment: derp.  For some reason I was thinking orthogonal.

Answer (score -1):

The definition of linear independence is that if $\sum q_n x_n = 0$, then $q_n = 0\  \forall n$.

So let's assume by contradiction that for all m, $\{y^{(m)}\}$ are linearly dependant.

Then $\sum q_n y_n^{(m)} = 0$, but not all $q_n =0$.

But $y_n^{(m)} \to x_n$, and therefore we have $\sum q_n x_n = 0$, but not all $q_n =0$.

This contradicts out hypothesis, and proves the assertion.

Edit: nevermind, I'm assuming that the coefficients stay the same.

Comment: ??? I suspect the OP knows this. I certainly know this, but it took me a few minutes to see how to answer the question....

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Here, I elaborated :)

Comment: This version is  simply wrong. You're assuming the same coefficients work for every $m$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yep, just noticed. I could fix it, but there's yours, so eh.